# Hoshen-Kopelman Algorithm MatLab Implementation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, implementation, union-find

First of all, I'm not 100% sure if Matlab is allowed on stack overflow; if I'm violating the rules tell me and I'll delete the question.

I'm currently studying percolation on a 2D surface (using a matrix for it), and I've written an algorithm that is able to check for percolation and label all cluster in a grid. The algorithm i wrote isn't very efficient and i've been tasked to implement the HK algorithm to do the same, more efficently since the HK doesn't "look behind".
FYI -> reticolo stands for grid, reticle
The "main" part of the program seems to work fine. Whenever i used my own way instead of the Find function i also found that in random grid where there aren't any cells that have BOTH up and left NN, everything works fine and the whole grid gets labelled correctly.
That also means that techincally the Union-Find part of the algorithm isn't really needed if the grid generated has cells that do not have both neighbors to the left and above, but that is clearly irrealistic.
What seems to be giving me problems is implementing correctly the Find function.
If anyone is able to help, I'd appreciate. Thanks

```
function A = HK(p,L)
    if nargin == 0,0;
        p = 0.55; 
        L = 4; 
    end
A.reticolo = rand(L)<p; % matrix field with prob p 
A.label = zeros(L);     % label field 
A.prob = p;             % prob field  
idx = reshape(1:L^2, L, L);
nnl = [zeros(L,1) idx(:,1:L-1)];   % find near neighbor (NN) on the left 
nnu = [zeros(1,L); idx(1:L-1,:)];  % find NN up  
largest_label = 1; 
    for i = 1:L^2 
        left = i-L; 
        up = i-1; 
        
         if(A.reticolo(i) && ~A.label(i)) %If the site is coloured and has no label 
             
                
              %if it has NN-left and NN-up 
              if (nnu(i) && nnl(i) && A.reticolo(nnu(i)) && A.reticolo(nnl(i))) %#ok<*ALIGN>
                 % A.label(i) = min(A.label(i-L), A.label(i-1)); -> i tried
                 % a workaround that didn't really work 
                 Union(left, up); 
               
              % If there's a NNL 
              elseif (nnl(i) && A.reticolo(nnl(i)))
                 A.label(i) = A.label(nnl(i)); %-> this is what i'm using
                 % since Find isn't working. This works for up and left cases.
                 % A.label(i) = Find(left); -> I should be using this instead 
               
              % If there's a NNU  
              elseif (nnu(i) && A.reticolo(nnu(i)))
                  A.label(i) = A.label(nnu(i));
                 %A.label(i) = Find(up) -> again, i should be using this instead of the line above 
                
              % If it doesn't have neighbours at all     
              else,  
                    largest_label = largest_label +1; 
                    A.label(i) = largest_label; 
                end  
         end 
    end     

    function F = Find(x)
        while A.label(x) ~= x %here there seems to be a problem, that i don' get 
            x = A.label(x);  
        end 
        F = x; 
    end 

    function Union(x,y)
        A.label(Find(x)) = Find(y);
    end 
end
```

And the errors I'm getting

```
    Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.
Error in HK/Find (line 56)
        while A.label(x) ~= x
Error in HK/Union (line 63)
        A.label(Find(x)) = Find(y);
Error in HK (line 32)
                 Union(left, up);
```

Comment: [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) is certainly supported, as 75.000 people have that tag on their watch list.  However, it is strongly encouraged to provide reproducible code including test data. Preferably, the code is shortened to just reproduce and illustrate the issue you're struggling with.  Also, it is recommended to nicely indent and format the code, to make it easier to read (many editors have functions to do this automatically).

Comment: When the `Find` function throws this error, what actually is the value of `x` that you are trying to use as an array index and why? Search the MATLAB help for `Debug a MATLAB program` if you need help with this.

Comment: @JohanC aside from the first line and 2 new lines skipped after the end function code seems decently indented to me.

Comment: @nekomatic thank you for your reply. When I call the Find function I'm giving either the Left or Upper neighbor cell index. In a square matrix (reading up->down) i-1 will give me the upper neighbor and i-L (side dimension) will give me my left neighbor. I thought find would look for labels based on the main grid matrix indexes so I gave that as input.